# Where is this rvalue residing if its lifetime is prolonged by const reference?

Tags: c++, constants, rvalue-reference

I've read through this question:

[Where is rvalue stored in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665310/where-is-rvalue-stored-in-c)

And according to the answer:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 7; // 7 rvalue is stored in the program binary and assigned to "a"
    int b = 7 * rand(); // 7 is pulled from the program binary, multiplied by result of rand and assigned to "b"

    // But...
    const int& c = 3; // 3 is an rvalue?
    const_cast<int&>(c) = 1; // rvalues don't have storage space? But I'm assigning to it.
    std::cout << c; // Prints 1
}
```

I want to understand, normally a rvalue temporary (right side of the equals sign) doesn't have storage space in memory and its lifetime ends at the end of the line. If we bind a const reference to it then it extends the lifetime of the rvalue to the lifetime of the reference it was bound to. In the case to assigning to "3", a number literal, does this mean it does get some storage space and isn't an rvalue? Or is an rvalue?

Also I would like to know if what I've done is undefined behaviour, regardless of the const_cast being inadvisable or whatever.

Comment: Where did you get "rvalues/temporaries have no storage space in memory" from? Sometimes compilers are awesome at optimizing, but generally objects require space, temporary or not.

Comment: @nwp Hmm, I'm probably wrong, it's just something I "remember" reading. I'll see if I can track down some links.

Comment: `const_cast<int&>(c) = 1;` Is undefined behaviour.

Comment: They will be stored at the same place as other objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: The compiler isn't required to compile `const int& c = 3;` any different from `const int c = 3;`.  All the declaration says is "c means 3".

Comment: @Richard Critten Can you just clarify, as VTT said that the "3" literal will be stored in the same place as automatic variables, is any const_cast on an auto variable undefined behaviour? Or only const_casting references, or only const_casting if referring to a number literal?

Comment: @Bo Persson then in that case is the const_cast undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Zebrafish A reference is just an alias.  `3` being a constant could be in a readonly segment of memory.  So we have an alias to truly readony value.  Infact `3` does not even have to exist in a storage location (in this example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> normally a rvalue temporary (right side of the equals sign) doesn't have storage space in memory

Normally it has a storage space, you should have misunderstood some concepts here.

> In the case to assigning to "3", a number literal, does this mean it does get some storage space and isn't an rvalue? Or is an rvalue?

Both: it is an rvalue and it has a storage space. There is [a space](https://godbolt.org/g/vtZwPD) on the stack which is allocated to store and integer with a value `3`, then `c` is bound to this variable.

Regarding your code:

```
const int& c = 3; // 3 is an rvalue?
```

Yes, it is rvalue.

```
const_cast<int&>(c) = 1; // rvalues don't have storage space? But I'm assigning to it.
std::cout << c; // Prints 1
```

From [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

> const_cast makes it possible to form a reference or pointer to
>   non-const type that is actually referring to a const object or a
>   reference or pointer to non-volatile type that is actually referring
>   to a volatile object. **Modifying a const object through a non-const
>   access path** and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile
>   glvalue **results in undefined behavior**.

Comment: I see. So any const_cast<> or something like const int* a; * (int*)a = 2; is always undefined? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Zebrafish an attempt to change a const value with a `const_cast` is UB.

Comment: I see. Then what is the point of const_cast<>? Is it only for example to pass to a function taking a non-const parameter that you're sure won't change its value?

Comment: @Zebrafish `int x=5; int const & y = x; const_cast<int&>(y)=42;` is not UB.; because the original storage was not constant.